# Insert using variables and another table's column

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, insert

I'm trying to write a "simple" *INSERT* comand in *SQL*.

```
INSERT TABLE_A (COLUMN_1_TABLE_A, COLUMN_2_TABLE_A, COLUMN_3_TABLE_A)
        VALUES (@variable_1, @variable_2, (SELECT * FROM TABLE_B))
```

Now, *TABLE_B* has one column and a variable number of rows.
How can I loop through all *TABLE_B* rows using its values for all the inserts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SELECT` statement with `INSERT INTO . .` :

```
INSERT TABLE_A (COLUMN_1_TABLE_A, COLUMN_2_TABLE_A, COLUMN_3_TABLE_A)
    SELECT @variable_1, @variable_2, b.COL
    FROM TABLE_B b
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.